# How to remove URLs with argument in google result

Tags: seo, search-engine, sitemap, google-search-console

I have a website which I have recently started and also submitted my sitemap on google webmaster tool. My site got index whiten short time but whenever I search about my website on google, I see two three version of my same pages with diff URL arguments on each

Means suppose my site name is example.com, so when I search about exmaple.com on Google I get the results like following

1. www.example.com/?page=2
2. www.example.com/something/?page=3
3. www.example.com

As I know result 1 and result 3 are same, why are they being shown separately ? I don't have any such URL in my sitemap and not even in any of my html page so why is this happening I am little confused. I want to get rid of it

Also result no 2 should be displayed simple as www.exaple.com/something
and not like www.example.com/something?page=3

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Go to Google Search console, navigate crawl \ url parameters and set them up.

Comment: thank you @AlexKudryashev for the comment it hinted me towards solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a setting in google webmaster tool which helps in removing URLs with parameters. To access & configure the setting, navigate to ***Webmaster tool --> Crawl --> URL Parameters*** and set them according to your needs

I also found **following article useful for understanding** concept behind those parameters and how could we remove pages getting crawled with unnecessary parameters

http://www.shoutmeloud.com/google-webmaster-tool-added-url-parameter-option-seo.html